# Pass id from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Actually I'm the beginner in the MVC. And simple question:

For example I have ViewModel for the page of Category:

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public int ProductId {get;set;}
    public int CategoryId {get;set;}
    public string ProductName {get;set;}
    public string CategoryName {get;set;}
}
```

In the controller I just pass `CategoryId` and `CategoryName` to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    CategoryViewModel categoryViewModel = new CategoryViewModel();
    categoryViewModel.CategoryId = catId; \\Get from DB
    categoryViewModel.CategoryName = catName; \\Get from DB

    return View("Category", categoryViewModel);
}
```

Then on the View I need to add Product to this Category:

```
<form action=@Url.Action("AddProduct", "Category") method="POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
    <textarea name ="ProductName"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
</form>
```

And in the controller for AddProduct:

```
[HttPost]
public ActionResult AddPost(CategoryViewModel categoryViewModel)
{
    var productName = categoryViewModel.ProductName;
    var categoryId = ?
    ProductRepository.AddProductToCategory(productName, categoryId);

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Question: How to get the `CategoryId`? Or maybe there is another approach?

Comment: You need to add a control for `CategoryId` in the form (e.g. `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CategoryId)`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your view to include a control for the `CategoryId` property

```
@model CategoryViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm("AddProduct", "Category"))
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CategoryId)
  @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ProductName)
  <input type="submit" value="Add" />
}
```

Note, always use strongly types html helpers to generate your html.

Answer (score 3):

Thx for **Stephen Muecke**

Also you can pass id from (form self) and another properties you want, but you must definition in  input action method.

```
@model CategoryViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddProduct", "Category", new { id = Model.CategoryId }, FormMethod.Post, new { }))
  {
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ProductName)
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
  }
```

Action method :

```
[HttPost]
public ActionResult AddPost(CategoryViewModel categoryViewModel,int id)
{
    var productName = categoryViewModel.ProductName;
    var categoryId = id
    ProductRepository.AddProductToCategory(productName, categoryId);

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

i hope this help you.